# How to define temporary function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to avoid writing repetitive code for tests and other cases.

Is there a better way other than using lambda with inconvenient dot call syntax `test_parse_tag.(...)`?

```rb
def test(name) = yield
def assert_equal(expected, actual) = p :tested

class El
  def self.parse_tag(s) = [:div, { class: 'some' }]
end

# I don't want to type `assert_equal El.parse_tag` every time
test 'El.parse_tag' do
  assert_equal El.parse_tag('span'),      [:span, {}]
  assert_equal El.parse_tag('#id'),       [:div,  { id: 'id' }]
  assert_equal El.parse_tag('div  a=b'),  [:div,  { a: 'b' }]
end

# So I use shortcut `test_parse_tag`
test 'El.parse_tag' do
  def test_parse_tag(actual, expected)
    assert_equal El.parse_tag(actual), expected
  end

  test_parse_tag 'span',      [:span, {}]
  test_parse_tag '#id',       [:div,  { id: 'id' }]
  test_parse_tag 'div  a=b',  [:div,  { a: 'b' }]
end

# PROBLEM, I don't want `test_parse_tag` to be available here
test_parse_tag 'span', [:span, {}]
```

Comment: For unit tests, you typically define a class to hold the tests, e.g. `class TestEl` – within that class you can define helper methods (e.g. `def assert_parse_tag`) as you like and without affecting other test classes.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, although I don't like that approach, you expose the method to the huge scope of whole class, when it's a local method needed only in a very tiny scope of one method.

Comment: Think about it: if you want some clear decision, why do you define private methods in the `Object` (parent class for most classes)?

Answer (score 2):

You could execute the block passed to `test` in the context of an object that you create beforehand. Here's a simple version using [`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) which passes the object along as a block argument, in case it's needed:

```
def test(name, &block)
  obj = Object.new
  obj.instance_exec(obj, &block)
end
```

By executing the block inside the object, methods are defined in the object's singleton class and won't leak out:

```
test 'one' do |context|
  def foo ; end

  defined? foo       #=> "method"
  context            #=> <Object:0x00007fd3b002c2f0>
  method(:foo).owner #=> #<Class:#<Object:0x00007fd3b002c2f0>>
end

test 'two' do |context|
  defined? foo       #=> nil
  context            #=> #<Object:0x00007fd3b0026fd0>
end

defined? foo #=> nil
```

RSpec takes this approach a step further: each example group creates a class and each example is evaluated in an instance of that class, see [A Word on Scope](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.12/rspec-core/#a-word-on-scope).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's better incapsulate tests in the class or use some library like RSpec or minitest

For your architecture structure I suggest to use [lambda](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Lambda+and+non-lambda+semantics) as local variable `test_parse_tag`. It will be unavailable outside the `test` block

```rb
def test(name) = yield
def assert_equal(expected, actual) = p :tested

class El
  def self.parse_tag(s) = [:div, { class: 'some' }]
end


test 'El.parse_tag' do
  test_parse_tag = ->(actual, expected) { assert_equal El.parse_tag(actual), expected }

  test_parse_tag.('span', [:span, {}])
  test_parse_tag.('#id', [:div,  { id: 'id' }])
  test_parse_tag.('div  a=b', [:div,  { a: 'b' }])
end
```